# Reserved word as argument in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a Python module that will be invoked as follows:

```
$> foo bar --fail 5 --pass 50
```

meaning that it will call the function `bar` over and over again with different values until I have 50 successful runs or 5 failed ones.

The problem here is that, since `pass` is a reserved word, the following piece of code will not work:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Something')
parser.add_argument('--fail', type=int, default=1)
parser.add_argument('--pass', type=int, default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()
[...]
passed = 0
failed = 0
while passed < args.pass and failed < args.fail:
  [...]
```

because of `args.pass`. Is there any way for renaming the element in the `args` namespace without it showing when I show the help?